# Get name and create a multidimensional array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this

```
<input data-sector="10" name="people" value="21">
<input data-sector="10" name="people" value="22">
<input data-sector="11" name="people" value="23">
<input data-sector="11" name="people" value="24">
<input data-sector="12" name="people" value="25">
```

and with jQuery, I need transform to this:

```
var json = {"10":[21,22], "11":[23,24], "12":[25]}
```

I use this, but wont work. I need help.

```
var code = [];
$('[name=people]').each(function () {
    var local = $(this);
    code[local.data('sector')].push.local.val();
});
```

Comment: You json is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `push` is a function, you have to call it with `()`.
2. `code` should be an object, not an array.
3. If the object property isn't already created, you have to create it with an empty array before you can push onto it.

```js
var code = {};

$('[name=people]').each(function() {
  var local = $(this);
  var sector = local.data('sector');
  if (!code[sector]) {
    code[sector] = [];
  }
  code[sector].push(local.val());
});

console.log(code);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-sector="10" name="people" value="21">
<input data-sector="10" name="people" value="22">
<input data-sector="11" name="people" value="23">
<input data-sector="11" name="people" value="24">
<input data-sector="12" name="people" value="25">
```